# Application needs a lot of unused dependencies

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I have an Eclipe E4 application. Now I ugrade my IDE environment to the newest Eclipse Oxygen release. Also I installed my regullar plugins in the IDE.

When starting my own E4 application from in Eclipse itself it gives a lot of missing module. But those modules I don't use in my application and it looks like it comes from all the installed plugins.

It is possible to only include the required plugins in my E4 application? Now I have 200+ dependencies in my application and most of them are not needed in my E4 application.

An error when starting the application is thrown and looks like:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.mylyn.builds.ui [6341]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories.ui; bundle-version="1.0.0"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories.ui; bundle-version="1.15.0.v20170411-1844"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories.ui [6350]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui; bundle-version="3.8.0"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui; bundle-version="3.23.0.v20170411-1844"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui [6352]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.google.guava; bundle-version="[21.0.0,22.0.0)"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui; bundle-version="3.8.0"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui; bundle-version="3.23.0.v20170411-1844"; singleton:="true"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.ui; bundle-version="1.0.0"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.ui; bundle-version="1.15.0.v20170411-1844"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.ui [6347]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui; bundle-version="3.8.0"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui; bundle-version="3.23.0.v20170411-1844"; singleton:="true"
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.workbench; bundle-version="3.8.0"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.workbench; bundle-version="3.23.0.v20170503-0014"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.workbench [6353]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui; bundle-version="3.8.0"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui; bundle-version="3.23.0.v20170411-1844"; singleton:="true"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1628)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1607)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1579)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1522)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Can someone help me cleanup my application dependencies?

Comment: The Plugins tab on the 'Run > Run Configuration' for your app is where you configure the plugins that are included when launching from within Eclipse.

Comment: Ok I found it. tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configured the plugins in the plugins tab:

greg-449:
'The Plugins tab on the 'Run > Run Configuration' for your app is where you configure the plugins that are included when launching from within Eclipse.'